# Pulling multiple alternatives from a variable in a case condition

Tags: environment-variables, scripts

I'd like to use variable as condition in case statement. Something similar to:

```
#!/bin/sh

ALLOWED_SERVICES=tomcat6|james;

case $1 in
    $ALLOWED_SERVICES )
        service $1 restart
    ;;
    * )
    echo "Unsupported argument"
    ;;
esac
```

This doesn't work. When script is started with *tomcat6* argument for exapmle, it outpoots *"Unsuported argument"* message.
But when case condition is hardcoded it works ok:

```
case $1 in
    tomcat6|james )
        service $1 restart
    ;;
    * )
    echo "Unsupported argument"
    ;;
esac
```

Is it possible to use variables in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trouble is that both variable expansion and pattern expansion need to be done before matching and that doesn't work here. If you have a recent version of `bash` available you could use regex matching:

```
#!/bin/bash

ALLOWED_SERVICES="tomcat6|james"

if [[ $ALLOWED_SERVICES =~ $1 ]]; then
  service $1 restart
else
  echo "Unsupported argument"
fi
```

Add `shopt -s nocasematch` before the `if` to make the matching case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Your first clode block wouldn't work, since it will try to pipe the output of `tomcat6` through the command `james`.

At any rate, `case` is probably not the right tool for this. Use an array and then check against that:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ALLOWED_SERVICES
ALLOWED_SERVICES=(james tomcat6)

for servicename in ${ALLOWED_SERVICES[*]};
do
        if [ "${servicename}" == "${1}" ];
        then
          service $1 restart
          exit
        fi

done

echo $0: Error: service \"$1\" not recognized
```

EDIT: also: use bash :-)

Comment: You use bash, the OP uses sh.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` that separates multiple alternatives is part of the shell syntax. You can't have it come from a string: the string would have to match, with the `|` character inside.

What you can do is check whether the service name appears as a substring in the list of allowed services, surrounded by delimiters. In other words, check if the list of allowed services contains the service as a substring. Put delimiters around the service name in case it's the first or the last one in the list.

```
case "$1" in
  *\|*) echo 1>&2 "$0: Invalid service name: $1"; exit 2;;
esac
case "|$ALLOWED_SERVICES|" in
  *"|$1|"*) service "$1" restart;;
  *) echo 1>&2 "$0: Unknown or forbidden service: $1"; exit 2;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in case conditions, but you cannot pass alternatives that way.
One way to do what you want would be to use eval:

```
#!/bin/sh

ALLOWED_SERVICES="tomcat6|james";

SERVICE="unknown"
[ -n "$1" ] && SERVICE="$1"

CHECKSRV=$(echo $SERVICE | sed 's/[a-z0-9_]*//i')
[ -n "$CHECKSRV" ] && exit 2


eval "
case \"$SERVICE\" in
    ${ALLOWED_SERVICES} )
        service \"$SERVICE\" restart
    ;;
    * )
    echo \"Unsupported argument\"
    ;;
esac
"
```

I personally would prefer another solution to using eval, but given the check with the sed filter, you should be good to go.